# Get line number from character position

Tags: perl

How can I locate the line where character n in file is located?

For example, how can I know where character 5347 is located in a given file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are reading from a filehandle line by line with line input operator, special variable `$.` gives current line.

Here is some sample code: it reads a file line, counting characters with `$pos`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt';

my $reference = 5347;
my $pos       = 0;

do {
    $pos += length <$fh>;
 } while ( $pos < $reference );

say $.;
```

Comment: So I should do a seek to the given position and then use `$.` to ge the line number?

Comment: Well, I think that `seek()` will not work as it doesn't update special variable `$.`

Answer (score 3):

This lightly tested code seemed to me to do the job:

```
my $desired = 5347;
my $char_count = 0;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    $count += length;
    if ( $count >= $desired ) {
        print $. . $/;
        last;
    }
}
```

Of course it assumes that `$fh` is an already opened filehandle that hasn't been read from yet.

Also note that it counts characters, not bytes, which is what you said, but might not have been what you meant.

Comment: OK. Like I suggested to @Marco, would it be possible to do a seek in order to prevent reading the whole document until we meet the position?

Comment: @Raphink: No, you need someone to count the lines for you - just seeking will not do that.  You can either read in the file "raw" and count line endings yourself until you reach your position, or read line by line and let perl count them for you, but one way or the other, someone has to count lines, right?